# How to smooth svg viewBox change?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have an SVG with the following viewBox values:

`viewBox="450 0 500 500"`

Every time a user clicks a button, the x-axis value increases by 80px. I want to know how smooth this transition in the x-axis.

Right now the transition is very sudden. I have found some information on how to make smooth transitions with SVGs but using transform/translate and delay, but is there any way to smooth transitions when one changes the viewBox values?

Thanks

Comment: Using javascript `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: Use SMIL to animate the values.

Comment: @RobertLongson How does that work? Do you have to dynamically add new `<animate>` elements to the SVG? I tried using alpine and just binding the viewBox value to a data value, but the animation only happened on the first change.

Comment: @Scribblemacher yes add new animate elements. You may need to adjust the timeline or manually begin the animation. If you want more information, ask a question.